Are /x/, the glottal stop /ʔ/, the nasal vowels /æ̃/ and /ɒ̃/, the rhotic vowels /ɚ/ and /ɝ/, and /ɜː/ (marginal) phonemes?
Are /x/, the glottal stop /ʔ/, the nasal vowels /æ̃/ and /ɒ̃/, the rhotic vowels /ɚ/ and /ɝ/, and /ɜː/ (marginal) phonemes? Some of then are obviously not standard phonemes in their own right, but I have seen some say /x/ is just a consonant with limited distribution, /ʔ/ is just an allophone of /t/, /æ̃/, /ɒ̃/, and /ɜː/ are loanword-only, /ɚ/ and /ɝ/ are "bird" vowels, some say /x/, /ʔ/, /æ̃/, /ɒ̃/, and /ɜː/ are marginal, some say it depends, but I might need a rough explanation, please, at one point yesterday, this was making my head hurt.

What do you mean by "(marginal) phonemes"? Just because some people use a glottal stop where others use a different phoneme doesn't change the fact that in those contexts where a glottal stop is used, you'd often either end up with a different word entirely, or complete nonsense, if you simply removed the glottal stop without adding back a replacement.

...also you might need to define what you mean by "phoneme" (and "rhotic vowel" is a new one on me). So far as I'm concerned, "x" isn't a phoneme in the first place, but that's completely different to the fact that not everyone uses glottal stops very often.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community Uh… what?


You don't need to know anything about this to be a highly competent English speaker.  If this is making your head hurt then stop! and go and learn some vocabulary instead (or read a book, or go play your favourite sport etc)

There are sounds, and then then there are phonemes.  Whether a particular sound occurs and whether that sound is a phoneme depends on dialect and accent.
In a phonemic transcription, one does not try to capture all the sounds, but to represent the sounds that are considered significant to the meaning of the words.   In a phonetic transcription one tries to capture the sounds that are produced.  A phonetic transcription should include "dark" and "light" l, a phonemic transcription won't.  Use [x] for the phoentic transcription and /x/  for the phonemic.
So in Liverpuddlian, [x] is a variant of [k] in some situations.  Native speakers are aware, and consider a Liverpuddlian's "[bax]" to be just a dialect variant of the standard [bak].  [x] does not occur in London dialects and it is not a phoneme, even in Liverpuddlian dialects, as /x/ does not contrast with /k/.
So  /x/ is not a phoneme of English.
The same analysis can apply to the other sounds.  An English listener does not consider "bottle" and "boʔle" as different words, but a variation in production of the same word, with the first giving the standard pronunciation.
You can compare this with say Arabic or Gaelic.  In the first the gottle stop is constructed with "t" and in the latter the fricative /x/ is constructed with /k/.
So what does this mean for the learner? You should attempt to produce sounds that are as close as possible to those in your chosen standard dialect of English.  But you should not worry too much if you are not perfect. Nobody can speak without an accent and provided your accent does not interfere with communication it is not a problem, but part of how you speak.

I've never seen the Liverpudlian BACK transcribed in "eye dialect" as "[bax]". Not knowing a more common alternative, I asked Google Gemini for the eye dialect version. It came back with three alternatives:  "Backeh": This adds an "h" to indicate the fricative aspect. "Backt": This uses a final "t" but might not fully capture the fricative nature. "Bac": Leaving the final consonant silent might be the closest written representation, relying on the reader's understanding of the Scouse accent. But I think it's more like Scottish loch, so I now think I'd just go with bach.

it's a lazy attempt at IPA.  May try to fix later.

oic - yeah, I don't really do IPA, but I do vaguely recall /x/ sometimes being used as a phonetic symbol for a sound completely unrelated to "x" in normal English orthography. I'll leave my second comment under the question itself, because that's what I thought at the time. But it looks like I was some way off the mark there, too.

I don't see anything wrong with [bax] it looks right and not lazy to me? Phonetically the BACK vowel in Scouse is probably [a]. Wikipedia gives it as [a] in a number of contemporary dialects (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet_chart_for_English_dialects) and while it is only Wikipedia I think it's probably right. Remember Daniel Jones's RP wasn't necessarily what even today's RP sounds like today and while the BACK vowel in English is often given phonemically as /æ/ that is not always its phonetic realisation

Also as you know the vowel quadrilateral and its cardinal vowels define the vowel space. They define the extremes, they're a set of reference points with respect to which real vowels of real languages and speakers can be mapped and plotted. As a result linguists have leeway in selecting the symbol they feel best represents the vowel in the language/dialect and often, if a language/dialect does not distinguish say æ and a or say ɛ and e well it's not unusual to pick the simpler symbol to make life easier for everyone. Not all linguists feel the need to show off with fancy symbols :P
